# css adding/removing padding to element depending of image width

Tags: html, css, image, conditional-statements, padding

I have an element of a %-width that contains a horizontally centered image of max-width 100%.

```
.container { width: 80%; )
.container img { 
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I'd like to add a padding-top to the container or a margin top on the image only when the container is wider than 100% of the orginal image width. 
E.g. when the browser window is very large or the image small, so that the image does not fully fill the container width.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Edited: the elements have a class, not an id. My problem refers to a tumblr layout and the elements are repeated for every post, so I cannot give them an id in the template...

Comment: Why not add a max-width tag to the image.

Comment: @Maverick: The images have very different sizes. They can scale smaller, but should never big larger than 100%....

Answer (score 0):

If your container's width is percentage-based and your image's max-width is set to 100%, the image will always expand to fill the container no matter what size it is. Meaning the container can never be larger than the image. Assuming this is not what you mean and that the image is a specific width, I've provided two possible solutions below.

---

It sounds like you want to apply the margin when the overall screen width is reduced (for a phone, perhaps). In which case, the easiest method is to use a media query in your CSS.

Start by defining the styles you'd like for the expanded version of your site like you have already (desktop or large tablet, whatever your target may be).

```
#container { width: 80%; )
#container img { 
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Then define your media query farther down in the CSS file at whatever breakpoint makes sense for your design.

```
@media (max-width: 320px){
    #container img {
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
}
```

Whenever the screen width is reduced to 320px or smaller, all CSS rules within this media query block will activate, allowing you to make changes dynamically.

---

If you aren't working on a responsive design like this and the screen size won't be changing, you might need to use some JavaScript to handle the styling changes.

First, create a class in your CSS that adds the margin.

```
.img-margin {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Use query selectors inside a script tag to grab hold of the elements you need to control and create a function that will handle checking for their respective sizes compared to one another and conditionally add/remove the margin class.

```
<script>    
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    var image = document.getElementById('image');

    container.addEventListener('click', toggleMargin);

    function toggleMargin(){
        if (container.offsetWidth > image.offsetWidth){
            image.classList.add('img-margin');
        } else {
            image.classList.remove('img-margin');
        }
    }
</script>
```

I've used the event listener for a click in the above example. You'll want to replace that with whatever event is occurring to trigger the change.

---

I advocate for the media query route, as it's far more elegant and doesn't require JavaScript, though the JS method can allow for more flexibility depending on your use-case.

Comment: Thank you @huntermacd for the detailed response!

- no, with container % and image max-width 100%, the image scales DOWN to the container width, but does not scale  more than its original width when the container is wider than the image 100%-width. This is what I want.

- I want to add a top-margin to the image, when the container gets bigger than the image width.

- It's for a tumblr layout. I cannot assign individual id's or classes to the various containers/images. If I could, your script would be a good solution, but I don't know how to get the container/image-width without id's. :-(

Comment: Good call on the max-width thing. I think I was thinking the image had `width: 100%` instead of `max-width: 100%`. Is the `#container` element id actually in the code or was that just used as an example? If it's in the code, you could nab that id and use `container.querySelectorAll('img)` to get ahold of an array of all images in that container. Then perform your check against the width of the specific image you need via its index:

`var container = document.getElementById('container');
var images = container.querySelectorAll('img');

images[0].offsetWidth`